# Si X s’est déjà levé, bizarre qu’il

Tags: constructions

Bonjour,

Le narrateur se réveille à cause du réveille-matin.

> Je relève la tête, jette un coup d’œil à ma droite puis promène mon
> regard autour de la chambre. La pièce est déserte et silencieuse. **Si
> Valérian s’est déjà levé**, bizarre qu’il n’ait pas arrêté la sonnerie.

D'après vous, la tournure *Si Valérian s’est déjà levé* est-elle appropriée dans mon contexte ? Est-ce que le syntaxe est correct ? Je pense que oui, mais j'ai des doutes.

Comment: Correcte, mais plutôt dans un dialogue, comme ici, ‘dialogue’ muet avec soi-même.

Comment: @Personne Merci, oui, c'est un dialogue intérieur avec soi-même.

Comment: J'aurais tendance à dire: "si Valérian est déjà levé" parce que l'état d'être levé importe plus que l'action de se lever.

Comment: Ce serait bien d'indiquer dans la question ce qui, dans l'expression *Si Valérian s'est déjà levé*, pourrait être incorrect.

Comment: @jlliagre La tournure _Si Valérian s'est déjà levé_ est correct, sans doute, mais je n'étais pas sûre qu'elle soit appropriée dans ma phrase. Je vais essayer de modifier ma question.

Comment: Ça ne nous dit toujours pas clairement sur quoi sont fondés tes doutes. Concernent-ils la logique ? le temps ? le mode ?

Comment: @jlliagre Le syntaxe, la logique, j'imagine. Je n'étais pas sûre que toute la phrase telle quelle _Si Valérian s’est déjà levé, bizarre qu’il n’ait pas arrêté la sonnerie._ soit correcte en français, mais j'avais l'impression qu'elle était passable à l'oral.

Answer (score 4):

> Si Valérian s’est déjà levé, [c'est] bizarre qu’il n’ait pas arrêté la sonnerie.

La phrase est à l'indicatif parce que « Valérian s'est déjà levé » est une hypothèse présumée vraie. Cette phrase conduit à douter de l'hypothèse, mais au début de la phrase, le doute n'est pas encore là.

On pourrait aussi utiliser le conditionnel dans la proposition principale et un temps passé dans la subordonnée introduite par *si*.

> Si Valérian **s'était** déjà levé, **ce serait** bizarre qu’il n’ait pas arrêté la sonnerie.

Le sens serait essentiellement le même, mais pas exactement. Avec le conditionnel, on conclut qu'à priori, Valérian n'est pas encore levé. Avec l'indicatif, il est encore plausible qu'il n'est pas levé et qu'il se passe quelque chose d'inhabituel.

On peut omettre « ce serait » en langage familier, mais c'est beaucoup moins naturel que d'omettre « c'est ».

Answer (score 1):

Comme mentionné par [Personne](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne) avant moi dans les commentaires, la phrase est ici présentée comme un dialogue à soi-même, donc cette construction reste correcte.